# VBA Format function outputs 2012 as 1232

Tags: excel, format, vba

I'm baffled as to why the line

```
Private Sub Date()
    Debug.Print Format(CDate("01-02-2012"), "mmmm yyy")
End Sub
```

Outputs "february 1232" instead of "february 2012"

Can someone explain why this happens or how to force it so that it displays the proper year

Comment: maybe it should be `"mmmm yyyy"`, also do you not get an error calling the sub Date()?

Comment: @Davesexcel, The sub Date () is just an example, I don't like to write just a single line of code but that is besides the point.

You are absolutely right though, I needed 4 y's instead of 3 which is odd because if you format a cell in Excel directly you only need 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The year can be "yy" for 12 or "yyyy" for 2012, "yyy".

You're looking for this:

```
Private Sub Date()
    Debug.Print Format(CDate("01-02-2012"), "mmmm yyyy")
End Sub
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I needed 4 y's instead of 3 which is odd because if you format a cell in Excel directly you only need 3.